# Magento Override Model Resource Category Tree file

Tags: magento

Trying to override app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\tree.php
    with config.xml

```
<global>
  <models>
    <catalog_resource>
      <rewrite>
         <category>Namespce_Modulename_Model_Resource_Category_Tree</category>
      </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource>
 </models>
</global>


and my class is defined in folder   local\Namespce\Modulename\Model\Resource\Category\Tree.php


class Namespce_Modulename_Model_Resource_Category_Tree extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree
{
  here is functions and code
}


it gives error  Call to undefined method Namespce_Modulename_Model_Resource_Category_Tree::checkId() in  app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php on line 671
```

Comment: i think you forget to close "/catalog_resource>" tag

Comment: No,I am not forget close  <"/catalog_resource> tag

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
 <global>
          <models>
        <catalog_resource>
              <rewrite>
                 <category_tree>Namespce_Modulename_Model_Resource_Category_Tree</category_tree>
              </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
            </models>
        </global>
```